# Custom 2D matrix operation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, multiplication

I have two sparse binary matrices `A` and `B` that have matching dimensions, e.g. `A` has shape `I x J` and `B` has shape `J x K`. I have a custom operation that results in a matrix `C` of shape `I x J x K`, where each element `(i,j,k)` is `1` only if `A(i,j) = 1 and B(j,k) = 1`. I have currently implemented this operation as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

I = 2
J = 3
K = 4

A = np.random.randint(2, size=(I, J))
B = np.random.randint(2, size=(J, K))

# Custom method
C = np.zeros((I,J,K))
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        for k in range(K):
            if A[i,j] == 1 and B[j,k] == 1:
                C[i,j,k] = 1

print(C)
```

However, the for loop is quite slow for large `I,J,K`. Is it possible to achieve this operation using numpy methods only to speed it up? I have looked at `np.multiply.outer`, but no success so far.

Comment: have you tried numba?
If the matrices are sparse, why not use their sparse representations? should be much faster to go over only the positions that contain non zero elements

Comment: @yannziselman not yet, but I am also considering it.

Comment: Sparse matrices are usually used for quite large arrays. Are you sure that you want to generate a non-sparse array C with shape (I,J,K) and not only the indices where the condition is fulfilled?

Comment: @max9111 yes, in reality I work with dimensions of approx 256, but also many more indices, so (I,J,K,L,M,...). That means the final array is not only fairly sparse, but also too large for numpy

Comment: this looks like an outer product that can be performed with broadcasting.  `scipy.sparse` is limited to 2d.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
C = np.einsum('ij,jk->ijk', A,B)
```

Comment: Always the `np.einsum`, thank you!

Comment: also `A[:,:,None]*B`

Answer (score 1):

Try to do what you're already doing with numba.
Here's an example using your code, Sehan2's method and numba:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

I = 2
J = 3
K = 4

np.random.seed(0)

A = np.random.randint(2, size=(I, J))
B = np.random.randint(2, size=(J, K))

# Custom method
def Custom_method(A, B):
    I, J = A.shape
    J, K = B.shape
    C = np.zeros((I,J,K))
    for i in range(I):
        for j in range(J):
            for k in range(K):
                if A[i,j] == 1 and B[j,k] == 1:
                    C[i,j,k] = 1
    return C

def Custom_method_ein(A, B):
    C = np.einsum('ij,jk->ijk', A,B)
    return C

@jit(nopython=True)
def Custom_method_numba(A, B):
    I, J = A.shape
    J, K = B.shape
    C = np.zeros((I,J,K))
    for i in prange(I):
        for j in prange(J):
            for k in prange(K):
                if A[i,j] == 1 and B[j,k] == 1:
                    C[i,j,k] = 1
    return C

print('original')
%timeit Custom_method(A, B)
print('einsum')
%timeit Custom_method_ein(A, B)
print('numba')
%timeit Custom_method_numba(A, B)
```

Output:

```
original
10000 loops, best of 5: 18.8 µs per loop
einsum
The slowest run took 20.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.32 µs per loop
numba
The slowest run took 15.99 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 5: 815 ns per loop
```

Note that you can make your code run much faster and more efficiently if you use sparse matrix representations. That way you avoid performing unnecessary operations.